# Rotating screen changes page in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation

My App has a login page and a main page with `UISplitView`.
After logout, when I rotate the screen, the login page disappears and the main page appears. If I click any button in the main page, the login page returns.
The problem occurs only in portrait to landscape rotation.
The logout button is in the master page of `UIsplitView`.
edit:
i build a simple program wit splitview and i have same problem.
its look like problem is in splitview
here is program:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsvBUWwFmkORXNUaVhiVVUzSjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It would help if you show some code.

Comment: Yes, as @auspicious99 said, some code would be helpful in order to detect the problem.

Comment: i build a simple program wit splitview and i have same problem. its look like problem is in splitview here is program: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwsvBUWwFmkORXNUaVhiVVUzSjg/edit?usp=sharing